# How to know what parameters a foldr's combine function should take?

Tags: scheme, racket

For the built-in function `foldr`, I know the function blueprint is the following:

```
(foldr combine base alist)
```

`combine` is supposed to take in two parameters:

1. an item that foldr consumes
2. the result of applying foldr to the rest of alist

I cannot seem to understand how to put point #2 in parameter form ever. How did you do it?

`combine` is not a built-in function. I would have to code it myself based on the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Think of second parameter as the accumulated value so far. For example, if we are adding the elements, then `acc` is the sum of all the previous `ele`s and we need to add the current element:

```
(foldr (lambda (ele acc) (+ ele acc))
       0 ; we're adding numbers, so the base is 0
       '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> 15
```

Another example - if we're copying the list, then `acc` contains the previous `ele`s in the list (starting from the last one and going back from there) and we have to `cons` the current element at the head :

```
(foldr (lambda (ele acc) (cons ele acc))
       '() ; we're creating a list, so the base is an empty list
       '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

The exact nature of `acc` depends on the problem to be solved, but you should be able get the idea from the previous examples.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as the result computed so far and that `foldr` iterates from end to beginning while a `foldl` iterates from beginning to end. It's easier to see if you look at a simple implementation of it:

```scm
(define (foldr1 f init lst)
  (let r ((lst lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        init
        (cons (f (car lst)) (r (cdr lst))))))          

(foldr1 combine base '(1 2 3))            ; ==
(combine 1 (combine 2 (combine 3 base)))

(define (foldl1 f init lst)
  (let r ((lst lst) (acc init))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (r (cdr lst) (f (car lst))))))

(foldl1 combine base '(1 2 3))            ; ==
(combine 3 (combine 2 (combine 1 base)))
```

Also note that the order or the arguments change in some implementations. Racket and [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) always have the accumulator as the last argument, but in R6RS the argument order changes for `fold-left` (but not `fold-right`):

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

;; swap argument order 
(fold-left (lambda (acc e) (cons e acc)) '() '(1 2 3))
; ==> (3 2 1)
```